# Leaflet custom length on polyline

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, leaflet, react-leaflet, polyline

Im currentyle using polylines to track the movement of something on a leaflet map.

Just for this example think about this.
I have an object with {lat, long} and when it updates it gets new atributes called {newLat, newLong}
Im drawing a polyline between this 2 points, but i want that polyline to always be the same length (lets say 100 meters).

[image: Polyline example]

So in that picture, the point moved from top to bottom and what im trying to achive its to keep the direction of the polyline to always be this length lets say

[image: Image that works]

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want the length in meters, or in pixels?

Comment: I would like it in meters